# How to print form name for each form?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I would like to show the system form name into the caption of the form. I think it's simple to know the name of the object form if it is displayed directly into the title.

How can I do for all the forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question boils down to two:

1. How to change the caption?

   ```
   this.design().caption(strFmt('[%1] %2', this.name(), this.design().caption()));
   ```
2. How to do it for all forms?

   Place your code in the `init` method of the `SysSetupFormRun` class.

Do not do this for end users. They could not care less.

Comment: About the SysSetupFormRun, you're right, bytheway , this.caption isn't working. Caption isn't recognize as method of SysSetupFormRun.